# Setting a reactive variable from inside a jquery click event block

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I  have been using jquery for some dom manipulation tasks and i have a need to update my reactive variables from inside the click event block.

I have this reactive variable

```
 data() {
  return {
inside_image:'' 
   };
  },
  mounted() {
  $("img").click(function() {
  var image_string = $(this).attr('src');
  this.inside_image = 'https://google.com/'+image_string;
});
```

that i need to update but i cant reach my data reactive var, most probably `this` isn't pointing to the vue data. Is there a method i can use to reach my reactive variables from inside the click event block?This block

```
$("img").click(function() {
  var image_string = $(this).attr('src');
 //This is currently not updating my reactive vars
  this.inside_image = 'https://google.com/'+image_string;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I saved the reference of `this` outside the block and worked

```
  var vue_this = this 
  $("img").click(function() {
  var image_string = $(this).attr('src');
  //alert(image_string);
  vue_this.inside_image = 'https://google.com/'+image_string;
});
```